# Python Sorting of HTML Tags on Page / CSS Columnization

Tags: python, html, css

**This code / markup...**

```
<ul id="tag-directory" class="clearfix">
        <li py:for="tag in tags"><a href="${h.url_for(controller='/media', action='index', tag=tag.slug)}">${tag.name}</a> (${tag.media_count_published})</li>
</ul>
```

**With this styling...**

```
#tag-directory {
    clear: both;
}

#tag-directory li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

**Produces alphabetical sorting in the browser like...**

```
A1               A2
A3               B1
B2               B3
B4               C1
C2               C3
```

**But what I want is...**

```
A1               B3
A2               B4
A3               C1
B1               C2
B2               C3
```

***How do I do that?***

---

Settled on Adam Wulf's JQuery plug-in: [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Uploaded Wulf's three .js files to server; then...

This markup in head of HTML file:

```
<head>
<script src="/scripts/third-party/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/scripts/third-party/autocolumn.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script> 
    $(function(){
        $('.wide').columnize({width:360});
    });
</script> 
<style> 
    .wide {clear:both;}
</style> 
</head>
```

And this markup in the body:

```
<div class="wide"> <!--per styling in head -->
    <ul id="tags" class="clearfix">
        <li py:for="tag in tags"> <!-- Python code dynamically generating hyperlinked li elements -->
            <a href="${h.url_for(controller='/linkedmedia', action='index', tag=tag.slug)}">${tag.name}</a> (${tag.linkedmedia_count_published})
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That's it.  Probably can compress the Javascript to speed up load time of page.  CSS3 is faster and quicker and generally more elegant solution in terms of simplicity, but Wulf's Javascript is a tolerable hack to get the same look on IE as CSS3 provides in modern browsers.  (What a pain IE is...!) Pure CSS solutions do not work for a dynamically generated list of li elements that are hyperlinks.  A screenshot of how resultant Columnizer solution appears in IE8 posted below...

[image]

Comment: Is it always 2 columns or is it "n" columns wide?

Comment: Presently, just 2...but probably okay if "n" columns.  As long as it lays out on the page okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Internet Explorer's lack of support is not an issue for you, you could use [CSS3 columns](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-multi-column-css3-module/).

Update in response to comment:

As your items are all in one list (and I assume you want to keep it that way), it's tricky. You might like to take a look at [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-the-multi-column-css3-module/) (pages 2 and 3 deal with fake columns), but to be honest I'd recommend considering CSS3 columns and allowing those with IE to see the list in one column. (Not ideal, but [Do websites need to look exactly the same in every browser?](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=1&cid=27F87) :-) )

As far as I know, other options would involve splitting the list up into two elements or getting involved with Javascript fudges.

Comment: @David...yup, you're right.  Nada...zero support for it in any version of IE.  That's a bummer.  I don't think I can fly with that.  I appreciate the suggestion, however.

Comment: @David...after exploring nearly every option, indeed, it seems the CSS3 solution is the most elegant and bulletproof.  I really wanted the columns to work on IE, however...so I settled on Adam Wulf's JQuery plugin, Columnizer:   http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin   I've redacted the code a little bit. I've included the code as an addendum to my question above.